# Kubernetes client-python creating a service error

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to create a new service for one of my deployments named `node-js-deployment` in GCE hostes Kubernetes Cluster

I followed the Documentation to [create_namespaced_service](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/client-python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#create_namespaced_service)

This is the service data:

```
{
    "kind": "Service",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "node-js-service"
    },
    "spec": {
        "selector": {
            "app": "node-js"
        },
        "ports": [
            {
                "protocol": "TCP",
                "port": 80,
                "targetPort": 8000
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the Python function to create the service

```
api_instance = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api()
namespace = 'default'  

body = kubernetes.client.V1Service()  # V1Serice

# Creating Meta Data
metadata = kubernetes.client.V1ObjectMeta()
metadata.name = "node-js-service"

# Creating spec 
spec = kubernetes.client.V1ServiceSpec()

# Creating Port object
ports = kubernetes.client.V1ServicePort()
ports.protocol = 'TCP'
ports.target_port = 8000
ports.port = 80

spec.ports = ports
spec.selector = {"app": "node-js"}

body.spec = spec


try:
    api_response = api_instance.create_namespaced_service(namespace, body, pretty=pretty)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling CoreV1Api->create_namespaced_service: %s\n" % e)
```

Error:

```
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Tue, 21 Feb 2017 03:54:55 GMT', 'Content-Length': '227'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Service in version \"v1\" cannot be handled as a Service: only encoded map or array can be decoded into a struct","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}
```

But the service is being created if I am passing JSON. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Never used client-python and thus can't help 100%. But I'd guess you at least forgot to assign the metadata object to body.metadata. Also, ports should have been an array with 1 element.

Comment: I missed to include the metadata in the question. In my code I actually did. May be it was about how I was trying to attach the ports. But finally ended up using dictionaries for deployment and services. It was simple and easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From reading your code, it seems that you miss assigning the metadata to `body.metadata`. And you missed that the `ports` field of the `V1ServiceSpec` is supposed to be a list, but you used a single `V1ServicePort` so without testing I assume this should works:

```
api_instance = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api()
namespace = 'default'

body = kubernetes.client.V1Service()  # V1Serice

# Creating Meta Data
metadata = kubernetes.client.V1ObjectMeta()
metadata.name = "node-js-service"

body.metadata = metadata

# Creating spec
spec = kubernetes.client.V1ServiceSpec()

# Creating Port object
port = kubernetes.client.V1ServicePort()
port.protocol = 'TCP'
port.target_port = 8000
port.port = 80

spec.ports = [ port ]
spec.selector = {"app": "node-js"}

body.spec = spec
```

The definition could also be loaded from json / yaml directly as shown in two of the examples within the offical repo - see [exec.py](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/client-python/blob/master/examples/exec.py) [create_deployment.py](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/client-python/blob/master/examples/create_deployment.py).

Your solution could then look like:

```
api_instance = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api()
namespace = 'default'

manifest = {
    "kind": "Service",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "node-js-service"
    },
    "spec": {
        "selector": {
            "app": "node-js"
        },
        "ports": [
            {
                "protocol": "TCP",
                "port": 80,
                "targetPort": 8000
            }
        ]
    }
}

try:
    api_response = api_instance.create_namespaced_service(namespace, manifest, pretty='true')
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling CoreV1Api->create_namespaced_endpoints: %s\n" % e)
```

Comment: passing the yaml as dictionary works perfectly, I have added the metadata to the body in my code bu failed to update it in the question. But like you said the problem might be on how I am passing the Ports not as a list.